# Firefox fails to render mono spaced font correctly

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

OK, here's my problem I thought that using Google Webfonts would take care of all the cross Browser mess for me, well guess what, I was wrong.

It turns out that Firefox does not like [Droid Sans Mono](http://code.google.com/webfonts/preview#font-family=Droid+Sans+Mono). In particular, it renders bold glyphs **WIDER** than the non bold ones, which turns out to be very unhandy when you're creating a terminal based hacking game in JS.

You can take a look at it here, wait a few seconds for the boot sequence to pass by, then look at the status line at the top:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2332843/os/os.html

Well, so now I'm in search of either a way to make Firefox render the whole thing correctly, or a good alternative to Droid Sans Mono.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google's sample page renders consistently between bold and normal when viewed in Chrome. Also, I confirm that the spacing changes in FF 3.5.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you need a font which has its own bold variant. Bold faces are often synthesized by user agents for faces that lack actual bold faces.  See:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-the-font-weight-property

One such monospaced font is [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).  This font has normal, bold and italic variants which render characters at the same width. It is legible at a font size of 10px.

[alt text http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/8166/dejavub.png](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/8166/dejavub.png)

Comment: Great, that did the Job, even though now I have the "smaller" problem with IE, but I guess I'll just serve that one with a conditional and the Android Font :)

Comment: That did not work for me. Even fonts which have their own bold font variants (e.g. Roboto Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono and many more I've tried) display wrong width, which is *really* annoying for viewing code diffs in Gerrit. I'm stuck with FF 52.1.0 ESR, and the only thing that worked was removing the bold style via the FF Add-on Stylish.

Comment: Actually, I found a better solution (still using the FF Stylish Add-on): I restated the font-family to the same family I use for monospaced fonts in the FF preferences, e.g. font-family: Roboto Mono. With that in the css code, it magically renders correctly.